# Acumulador de tiempo en c++

Tags: c++

estoy realizando un programa para capturar la hora de entrada y salida de x Persona, quisiera saber como hago para ir acumulando el tiempo que esa persona duro en x lugar.
Ejemplo
Persona 1
Entrada: 9:30
Salida: 11:45

Como hago para obtener ese tiempo 1h 15min. Alguno me puede dar una idea por favor. Ahorita la parte de codigo que tengo es: get y set de hora entrada y salida.

La hora de entrada y salida la obtengo de la siguiente forma:

```
  // Hora de entrada
time_t tiempoEntrada = time(0);
tm *obtieneEntrada = localtime(&tiempoEntrada);
string horaEntrada =  to_string(obtieneEntrada->tm_hour)+":"+to_string(obtieneEntrada->tm_min)+":"+to_string(obtieneEntrada->tm_sec); 

// Hora de salida
time_t tiempoSalida = time(0);
tm *obtieneSalida= localtime(&tiempoSalida);
string horaSalida =  to_string(obtieneEntrada->tm_hour)+":"+to_string(obtieneEntrada->tm_min)+":"+to_string(obtieneEntrada->tm_sec);
```

Comment: Puedes usar 3 bucles for o la librería time.h

Answer (score 3):

`time_t` es un tipo que almacena el número de segundos que han pasado desde 1 de enero de 1970.

Es decir, dadas dos variables `time_t`, calcular el número de segundos entre ambas fechas es tan sencillo como hacer la resta:

```
int intervalo = static_cast<int>(salida - entrada);
```

Una vez calculada la diferencia, sacar las horas, minutos y segundos es trivial:

```
int horas = intervalo / 3600;
intervalo -= horas * 3600;
int minutos = intervalo / 60;
int segundos = intervalo % 60;

std::cout << horas << " Horas, " << minutos << " minutos, " << segundos << " segundos\n";
```

Otra forma de calcular exactamente lo mismo:

```
int horas = intervalo / 3600;
int minutos = (intervalo % 3600) / 60;
int segundos = intervalo % 60;
```

Comment: Hay alguna forma de restar string, es que yo pase la hora de entrada y salida a string. O alguna forma de ese valor pasarlo de nuevo a time_t

Comment: @Keylor los strings son strings y los números son números... si quieres restar strings. El microprocesador te ofrece restar números, si quieres restar cadenas tendrás que programarlo tu... te compensa realmente?

Comment: @Keylor por otro lado, en tu ejemplo yo veo `tiempoEntrada` y `tiempoSalida`, que no son strings... la idea es usar esas variables

Comment: si señor, es que tuve que pasarlo a string, para guardalo en un txt y mostrar al usuario el tiempo h/m/s

Comment: @Keylor te saldría más a cuenta aislar el código que convierte a string en una función y usar el tipo original, en serio